# Dynamically change a ruby variable based on dropdown without refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to dynamically change a ruby variable based on a dropdown box in my view template.  In this example - I have a results page and want to change the number of results based on the dropdown.  So if I select 5 - I want the number variable to update 5 and the loop to only display 5 items.

I want to do this without a page refresh.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<form action="/form" method="get", name="myform" id="myform" role="form">

 <input type="text" id="text1">

</form>



<select id="filterresults" name="filterresults">
       <option value=4>4</option>
       <option value=9>9</option>
</select>



<div id="resultstable">

<%@myarray[0..@number].each do |i| %>

      <%=variable1%>

<%end%>


</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $("#filterresults").change(function(){



 var numresults = document.getElementById('filterresults').value;

 var input = $("<input>")
           .attr("type", "hidden")
           .attr("name", "filterresults").val(numresults)
           .attr("class","form-control");
 $("#myform").append($(input));

 $('#resultstable').load(document.URL +  ' #resultstable');


 });
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 @number = params["filterresults"]
```

Comment: Once the page is rendered in the browser, there is no more ruby variables. If you want to change the page without refresh, you must do it in Javascript. You can can create/delete elements (DOM), or just show/hide them.

Comment: So I'd have to duplicate my ruby loop code in javascript to display my elements?